# How to pull stock price when each line has a different ticker and date?

Tags: python, loops, append, finance, datareader

I'm trying to pull the `Adj Close Price` for the separate Tickers and Dates below. The formula I'm using is below

```
new_data = []
i = 0

while True:
    if i <= len(dfh3['TICKER']):
        bio_ticker = dfh3.iloc[i,0]
        bio_lockup = dfh3.iloc[i,7]
        new_data.append(web.DataReader(bio_ticker,'yahoo',bio_lockup,bio_lockup)['Adj Close'])
        i = i +1

dfh3['Adj Close'] = new_data
```

However, instead of only adding the 'Adj Close' Price. It's adding all the information pulled from DataReader (see below)

Original Dataframe:

| Ticker | Lockup Date |
| --- | --- |
| ADGI | 2022-02-02 |
| INAB | 2022-01-26 |
| OMGA | 2022-01-26 |

Current Output from my code:

| Ticker | Lockup Date | Adj Close Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADGI | 2022-02-02 | Date 2022-02-02 7.9 Name Adj Close, dtype... |
| INAB | 2022-01-26 | Date 2022-01-26 3.19 Name Adj Close, dtype... |
| OMGA | 2022-01-26 | Date 2022-01-26 11 Name Adj Close, dtype: .. |

Desired Output:

| Ticker | Lockup Date | Adj Close Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADGI | 2022-02-02 | 7.9 |
| INAB | 2022-01-26 | 3.19 |
| OMGA | 2022-01-26 | 11 |

I think the problem is stemming from the original creation of the 'new_data' list, but I'm not sure of an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the current output you provided it seems that every output is the same format:

"Date" space "the data" space "the price"...

So you can use the split method on the Adj Close Price string and grab the third item:

```
ADJ = "Date 2022-02-02 7.9 Name Adj Close, dtype...".split(" ")
print(ADJ[2])
```

output:

```
7.9
```

You can read more about the split method here: [docs for split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)